# Get serialized json request from Nest (ElasticSearch)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to get the json that Nest generates to send to ElasticSearch?

In my specific case, I want to compare the mapping on the server vs what the current document object would generate.

I can always create a temporary index and compare the mappings, but since Nest is generating it anyway, would like to avoid it.

Using Nest 0.12.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To see the JSON for indexing document:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourItem, Formatting.Indented,_client.IndexSerializationSettings);
```

where _client is your ElasticClient

Comment: ElasticClient does not have a property called IndexSerializationSettings.

Comment: @mkc you can use `.DisableDirectStreaming()` in your settings and `.OnRequestCompleted(details =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("### ES REQEUST ###");
                    if (details.RequestBodyInBytes != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes));`